# Invertir cadena usando Streams en Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

quisiera invertir el orden de una cadena de texto usando el Java Stream API de Java 8.

Esto es lo que he intentado, pero no realiza la inversión.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ReversedStrings {

  public static String solution(String str) {
    final Comparator<String> compareTo = String::compareTo;
    return Stream.of(str).sorted(compareTo.reversed()).collect(Collectors.joining());
  }
}
```

Si necesitan una prueba unitaria les comparto el código de la prueba unitaria que uso con JUnit

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ReversedStringsTest {
  @Test
  public void sampleTests() {
    assertEquals("dlrow", ReversedStrings.solution("world"));
  }
}
```

¿Hay alguna manera de invertir una cadena usando streams?

Comment: Le estás dando un único elemento String para comparar y lo compara completo con los demás elementos de la lista DE UN ELEMENTO. Lo que tienes que volver Stream es el conjunto de chars, usando `chars()` por ejemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si es posible hacerlo. Yo he usado la funcion chars() que devuelve un intStream que contiene cada letra representada en ascii. Luego se convierte cada letra a String y se reduce concadenando cada letra al principio del acumulador.

```
String str = "letras";
str.chars()
   .mapToObj(e -> String.valueOf((char)e)) //convierte cada letra a String
   .reduce((a, e)-> e.concat(a)) //concadena todo pero con el orden contrario
   .ifPresent(System.out::println);//esta linia solo imprime la palabra
```

Answer (score 1):

#### No creo que exista una manera de hacerlo siguiendo el mantra de los Streams

Un Stream tiene como cometido expresar **qué hacer para cada elemento de una colección subyacente, no cómo iterar sobre ella** Para este propósito, **los Streams [no guardan estado](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps)** (primer item).

Eso te va suponer un problema si quieres revertir la cadena usando solo Streams, puesto que para revertirla vas a tener que iterar y guardar los resultados intermedios en una colección temporal.

A mi juicio, este es uno de esos casos en los que es mejor utilizar una colección clásica que hacerlo con Streams, o utilizar las clases designadas para ello.

#### Entonces, ¿cómo lo hago sin Streams?

Yo usaría [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), te permite trabajar al estilo pipeline, como los Streams, y está específicamente diseñado para modificar un String:

```
public static String solution(String str) {
    return new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
}
```